# Add key to plist in buildtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, build-time

I want to add a key to `[AppName]-Info.plist` in built time. It is possible? How can I do this in built time.

Let me explain what i'm trying to do here:
I am writing a library and I want to read bundleIdentifier from app when developer want to release app. And add the key to info.plist contains this information.

Maybe I can write to this in runtime?

Comment: (And you can not write to the Info.plist at runtime. The application bundle is read-only.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mac right now to write exact steps to do it. But I'm sure you can do it.
You need to create custom build step - run shell script. In this script you should find out required identifier. Then using command line "default" script write required information to your plist. Last thing - you should change build order. Custom script required to launch before any other step build procedure.
Hope it helps.